# Using TLS only with Retrofit in RoboSpice

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit, okhttp, robospice

I've got a basic setup using Robospice with Retrofit in a shell Android application making REST calls, parsing JSON response into a POJO and that I can then use to render in an Activity. I now want to use TLS only for transport security (not SSL). I've read that Retrofit with OkHttp can be used to achieve this but I don't know where to make the update in my code.

I have a basic interface:

```
public interface RandomAPI {
    @GET("/users")
    List<User> getUsers(@Path("owner") String owner, @Path("repo") String repo);

    @GET("/users/{userid}")
    User getUser(@Path("userid") int userID);
}
```

I have a Service:

```
public class RandomService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

private final static String BASE_URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    addRetrofitInterface(RandomAPI.class);
}

@Override
protected String getServerUrl() {
    return BASE_URL;
}
}
```

and finally a request:

```
public class RandomRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<User, RandomAPI> {

private int userID;

public RandomRequest(int userID) {
    super(User.class, RandomAPI.class);
    this.userID = userID;
}

@Override
public User loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    return getService().getUser(userID);
}

}
```

I'm guessing I need to update the Service but not really sure how. I really like the simplicity of this pattern so would like to keep it if possible. I can drop the OkHttp jars into the application but I don't know how to get at the actual implementation of the service, or how to add my custom one so that all requests use it.

Has any one had experience with this that could share some code snippets or point me to an example?

**~~ EDIT ~~**

Looking into the API for Robospice, looks like my request can just extend SpiceRequest, then within the loadFromNetwork() method I just do plain Retrofit and OkHTTP stuff. Is that the only way though? Thought there would be a way to set your own `RestAdapter` implementation in [`RetrofitSpiceService`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/robospice-retrofit/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/retrofit/RetrofitSpiceService.java) instead of just using the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this is actually quite simple. Create a class which extends `RetrofitGsonSpiceService` and override the `createRestAdapterBuilder()` method.

e.g.

```
@Override
protected Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(SERVICE_URL)
        .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    return builder; 
}
```